# GraphQL mutation issue

Tags: graphql

I am new in GraphQL. I am learning GraphQL.

My input is like below

```
mutation {
  createEvent:{eventInput: {title: "A Test", description:"Does this work?", price:9.99, date:"2018-12-06T09:26:30.645Z"}
    }
}
```

I am getting error like below

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Syntax Error: Expected Name, found {",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 15
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I believe your `createEvent` mutation should return an object type. And for the object type , you have to specify at least one of the field from of return type for this Mutation.

It should be :

```
mutation {
  createEvent(eventInput: {
        title: "A Test" 
        description:"Does this work?"
        price:9.99
        date:"2018-12-06T09:26:30.645Z"
    }){
        someFieldInTheReturnType
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear. It would be more nice if you accept my answer and vote me up :D